# Auth0-React Frontend, with express-openid-connect Backend: How to Avoid Multiple Authentications for the User?

Tags: authentication, openid-connect, mern, auth0, express-openid-connect

I’m developing an app with MERN stack. I used express-openid-connect for Auth0 authentication for my server. I followed the guide for the openid implementation and everything is working fine on the backend. I get the logged in user details and store them in my Mongodb database. Now, I'm trying to implement the authentication for my react frontend, and I tried using the guide seen here: [https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login#add-logout-to-your-application]

When I click Login on my frontend, I was expecting the Auth0 authentication window but get "There could be a misconfiguration in the system or a service outage".

Should I have two Auth0 applications, one SPA for using auth0-react for authentication for my frontend and the already done express-openid-connect as my authentication for my server? Also, I don't understand if I am authenticating twice with this approach. Am I missing something?

Comment: I used the same ClientID, domain of the Auth0 application that I used for my backend, and verified it to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If your react frontend has a dedicated backend, then you don't need both the auth0-spa-sdk and express-openid-connect. Instead, you can just use the express-openid-connect and then use the session created by express-openid-connect to store the user information and the cookie it generates will provide the user session. You don't need to store any tokens in your react app. Just make sure that all the calls are to the same domain (when calling your backend). And make sure that your API client is configured to pass cookies.

Then, you just create a `/login` endpoint on your backend and when someone clicks login on your frontend, it calls login in the express-openid-connect backend which will redirect the user to Auth0 by Okta to signin.

You also have to configure your API calls (on your backend) to *not* automatically redirect, but instead return a 401. Then if your frontend ever receives a 401 on any of its API calls, you redirect to `/login` on your backend.

You will do the same with logout. When someone clicks logout, you POST to your `/logout` endpoint on your backend, which will call logout on the express-openid-connect SDK. You need to make sure that is configured to redirect to Auth0 by Okta for logout as well (the documentation will show you how). This will ensure their SSO session is killed at your Auth0 by Okta tenant.

This will make your SPA more secure as it will act more like a regular webapp security wise.